# I cannot get my variable to update between classes and tabs with a wx event call

Tags: python, wxpython

If you run this code, you will get default values from a combo box on Panel One, but after changing the values on Panel 2, the values being called from the Panel 1 button do not reflect the change in values on Panel 2.

```
    import wx

class PanelOne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)

        self.button1 = wx.Button(self, -1, label="Panel 1 Test",
            pos=wx.Point(100, 100))
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button1Click, self.button1)


    def button1Click(self,event):
        p2=PanelTwo(self, 0)
        print "Panel 1: %s" % p2.C1
        print "Panel 1: %s" % p2.C2


class PanelTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)

        # Default Declarations
        self.C1 = List1[0]
        self.C2 = List2[-1]

        self.combo1 = wx.ComboBox(self, -1, value=List1[0], pos=wx.Point(100, 30),
        size=wx.Size(100, 150), choices=List1, style = wx.CB_READONLY)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.EvtCmb1, self.combo1)

        self.combo2 = wx.ComboBox(self, -1, value=List2[-1], pos=wx.Point(300, 30),
            size=wx.Size(100, 150), choices=List2, style = wx.CB_READONLY)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.EvtCmb2, self.combo2)    

        self.button1 = wx.Button(self, -1, label="Panel 2 Test",
            pos=wx.Point(100, 100))
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button1Click, self.button1)


    def button1Click(self,event):
        print "Panel 2: %s" % self.C1
        print "Panel 2: %s" % self.C2

    def EvtCmb1(self, event):
        combo1 = (event.GetString())
        self.C1 = combo1

    def EvtCmb2(self, event):
        combo2 = (event.GetString())
        self.C2 = combo2



class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Testing 123", size = (500, 400) )

        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)

        panel1 = PanelOne(nb,-1)
        panel2 = PanelTwo(nb,-1)

        nb.AddPage(panel1, "Page One")
        nb.AddPage(panel2, "Page Two")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)


#Combo1
List1 = ['Apple', 'Banana']
#Combo2
List2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]


app = wx.App(redirect=False)
frame = MainFrame()
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I find your code confusing, but I think I found the problem. Consider your `PanelOne.button1Click()` function:

```
def button1Click(self,event):
    p2=PanelTwo(self, 0)
    print "Panel 1: %s" % p2.C1
    print "Panel 1: %s" % p2.C2
```

You're creating a new instance of `PanelTwo` every time, meaning it will always have the default values. Think of classes like makes and models of cars. I can have a Toyota Camry and you can have a Toyota Camry. They are the same type (class) of car, but they are seperate cars (different instances). Any change I make to *my* Camry obviously won't affect *yours* since they are different objects entirely. So following this analogy, everytime `PanelOne.button1Click()` is called, it buys a new Camry (creates a new instance); it doesn't get an already existing one. That new car comes fresh from the factory with all the default options regardless of how other owners modify their cars.

So basically, your `panel1` instance and your `panel2` instance aren't talking to each other at all, so `panel1` can't know anything about the state of `panel2`. You have a few ways you can solve this. The easiest way is to pass `panel2` as an `init` argument for `panel1`. Like this:

```
class PanelOne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, p2):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)

        self.p2 = p2 #store panel2 so we can check it later

        #do the rest of your setup

   def button1Click(self,event):
        print "Panel 1: %s" % self.p2.C1
        print "Panel 1: %s" % self.p2.C2

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Testing 123", size = (500, 400) )

        panel2 = PanelTwo(nb,-1)
        panel1 = PanelOne(nb,-1, panel2) #panel1 needs to be able to read panel2's settings

        #do the rest of your setup
```

This still isn't a great solution. Generally, I'd try to come up with something using [PubSub](http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxLibPubSub) to pass the information between classes without causing a dependency (i.e. note how `PanelOne` can never exist wthout `PanelTwo`, even in your original code), but I think that's overly complicated for your purposes.